# Обренуть значения словаря python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Допустим у нас есть вот такой словарь:

`{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}`

Как этот словарь, превратить в вот такой?:

`{'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто берёте пары ключ-значение в обратном порядке:

```py
d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
print(dict(reversed(d.items())))
```

Вывод:

```
{'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```